# "Add post" sometimes overwriting a previous post Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching, overwrite, posting

I have this issue with my wordpress site, sometimes posting a new post will overwrite a previous post. Specially one of my writers is suffering from this problem very much.
I am using litespeed cache. I've also enabled Redis object caching on my website recently but I had the problem before enabling it too.

Comment: If you disabled litespeed cache and Object cache, does issue still exist? Any other cache plugin you are using with?

Comment: I am only using litespeed cache as a caching plugin and if I disable the litespeed cache my issue will be solved

Comment: I see. The LSCache plugin may not cache those admin pages and I didn't see similar issue happens on lscache forum so far. I may guess it's due to object cache, although you claimed issue happens before object cache enabled.  Please clean & disable object cache and see if issue still. You can also join [golitespeed](https://golitespeed.slack.com/join/shared_invite/enQtMzE5ODgxMTUyNTgzLWVhZDNhZDNmYWRhZmIwNzUxN2Y2ZDRjZGUwZjFiMDk1ZTNjZDJmMDg5NTcyZjFiZDM4MDY1NjkwYjkzM2E5YmE) -> wpcache channel for direct message help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a htaccess file with below content in wp-admin folder.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
 ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 0 seconds"
</IfModule>

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [NS,E=no-gzip:1,E=dont-vary:1]
```